# What is the difference between ARM architecture and ARM core?

Tags: arch-linux, arm, cpu-architecture

I read the data sheet of the TI - DM385 , in which they have mentioned as:

> ```
> ARM Cortex-A8 Core
>  - ARMv7 Architecture
> ```

What's the difference?

Comment: This is unrelated to Unix or Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Cortex A8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-A8) is a specific processor design in the [ARM v7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM7) family.

It's like how an [Intel Celeron D Processor 325](http://ark.intel.com/products/27109/Intel-Celeron-D-Processor-325325J-256K-Cache-2_53-GHz-533-MHz-FSB) can be described as a processor in the 64-bit Intel [EM64T family](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64), or as a processor in Intel's [Northwood-128 family](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celeron#Northwood-128).

That is, an ARM Cortex A8 describes a specific design, whereas ARM v7 describes the CPU instruction set, gives a minimum set of registers, etc.

It's a bit different in the ARM world, where the processor design is licensed by [ARM Holdings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Holdings) to multiple CPU design houses, who in turn may use multiple different foundries may produce "Cortex A8" type processors. Nevertheless, "Cortex A8" is a more specific description than "ARM v7".